# Atlassian Forge Tunnel not working; how can I debug?

Tags: jira, atlassian-forge

- Mac OS Big Sur 11.7.10
- Node v18.15.0
- Docker 24.0.6
- Forge 7.0.2

Created a brand new app using `forge create`

When I try `forge tunnel` I get:

```
Tunnel redirects requests you make to your local machine. This occurs for any Atlassian site where your app is installed in the specific development environment. You will not see requests from other users.

Press Ctrl+C to cancel.
```

Then it just hangs... nothing more.

No VPN, firewall, or proxy running. I have Docker desktop installed and running.

Anything I can try? Or is there a way to get verbose logs to debug?

Docker info returns:

```
Client:

 Version:    24.0.6

 Context:    desktop-linux

 Debug Mode: false

 Plugins:

  buildx: Docker Buildx (Docker Inc.)

    Version:  v0.11.2-desktop.5

    Path:     /Users/my_username/.docker/cli-plugins/docker-buildx

  compose: Docker Compose (Docker Inc.)

    Version:  v2.22.0-desktop.2

    Path:     /Users/my_username/.docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose

  dev: Docker Dev Environments (Docker Inc.)

    Version:  v0.1.0

    Path:     /Users/my_username/.docker/cli-plugins/docker-dev

  extension: Manages Docker extensions (Docker Inc.)

    Version:  v0.2.20

    Path:     /Users/my_username/.docker/cli-plugins/docker-extension

  init: Creates Docker-related starter files for your project (Docker Inc.)

    Version:  v0.1.0-beta.8

    Path:     /Users/my_username/.docker/cli-plugins/docker-init

  sbom: View the packaged-based Software Bill Of Materials (SBOM) for an image (Anchore Inc.)

    Version:  0.6.0

    Path:     /Users/my_username/.docker/cli-plugins/docker-sbom

  scan: Docker Scan (Docker Inc.)

    Version:  v0.26.0

    Path:     /Users/my_username/.docker/cli-plugins/docker-scan

  scout: Docker Scout (Docker Inc.)

    Version:  v1.0.7

    Path:     /Users/my_username/.docker/cli-plugins/docker-scout

 

Server:

 Containers: 1

  Running: 0

  Paused: 0

  Stopped: 1

 Images: 2

 Server Version: 24.0.6

 Storage Driver: overlay2

  Backing Filesystem: extfs

  Supports d_type: true

  Using metacopy: false

  Native Overlay Diff: true

  userxattr: false

 Logging Driver: json-file

 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs

 Cgroup Version: 2

 Plugins:

  Volume: local

  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay

  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries splunk syslog

 Swarm: inactive

 Runtimes: io.containerd.runc.v2 runc

 Default Runtime: runc

 Init Binary: docker-init

 containerd version: 8165feabfdfe38c65b599c4993d227328c231fca

 runc version: v1.1.8-0-g82f18fe

 init version: de40ad0

 Security Options:

  seccomp

   Profile: unconfined

  cgroupns

 Kernel Version: 6.4.16-linuxkit

 Operating System: Docker Desktop

 OSType: linux

 Architecture: x86_64

 CPUs: 8

 Total Memory: 7.672GiB

 Name: docker-desktop

 ID: 9644cbbe-d113-4fa3-a7df-0f91f9bc52ba

 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker

 Debug Mode: false

 HTTP Proxy: http.docker.internal:3128

 HTTPS Proxy: http.docker.internal:3128

 No Proxy: hubproxy.docker.internal

 Experimental: false

 Insecure Registries:

  hubproxy.docker.internal:5555

  127.0.0.0/8

 Live Restore Enabled: false


WARNING: daemon is not using the default seccomp profile
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer – you have to set up Ngrok first https://developer.atlassian.com/platform/forge/tunneling/?_ga=2.206551187.129054678.1710258805-1599633662.1710258805#providing-credentials-for-ngrok